# Ideas for solofying for cello

Tags: cello

I'm looking for some schemes to solofy a simple tune on cello. Some obvious things, like adding a fancy bassline fail in this case of course.

As an example let's take this simple tune.

[image]

One obvious idea is to add some double stops.
Are there other stereotypical recipes?

By solofying I mean things you can do to the score to create sheet music that has more ornaments and is more interesting to listen at when played by a single instrument.

Comment: _Morgen, Kinder, wird's was geben_? Christmas is over...

Comment: Yes! It's the melody of Morgen, Kinder, wird's was geben just an example for a simple tune. (The song is Morgen, Kinder, wird's nichts geben by Erich Kästner btw :-))

Comment: Any particular reason why you want the melody to stay in the lowest bass register? Setting it as a tenor chant would give you many more opportunities of using other strings for accompaniment, and in my opinion sounds better anyway.

Comment: @KilianFoth No particular reason. Transposing it in a higher register is a good idea. I really love those low notes, but yes you surely are right. Thank you.

Comment: I might start by doing an analysis of the chord progression (and/or key progression if any) and building the support notes around the intended chord structures.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I had to play this piece solo, I might do something like this:

[image: Ornamented solo cello version]

Comment: Wow! Great effort! Thank you very much. You used many pattern there, I'll be able to extract and list them on my own. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

I can't find a translation in german and find whether an explanation nor synonyms of solofie and solofying in english.
but if you mean to play a solo or variation of the given tune (and others) try by fill the  crotchets with eighth notes with an other chord note. find out and  write down the chord progression of the tune and compose a little variation using this chord notes, returning notes and passing notes (diatonic and chromatic)

Comment: In this case I can give you another hint: just play the first basic note of each chord and the fifth with upper diatonic returning note or lower chromatic returning note as in blues or boogie woogie (do so la so or do so fi so) and at instead of the last half note of the first line: so fa mi re do (all as 8th notes) and listen to the last section of the 6th symphony of Beethoven.